# In JavaScript, Iterating over generator using for-of loop ignore return statement why?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, for-of-loop

**Take a close look at code**

```js
function* NinjaGenerator() {
  yield "yoshi";
  return "Hattori";
}
for (let ninja of NinjaGenerator()) {
  console.log(ninja);
}

// console log : yoshi
```

**Why "Hattori" is not logged ?** Where as when we iterate over iterator using iterator.next() it show that value.

```js
function* NinjaGenerator() {
  yield "yoshi";
  return "Hattori";
}

let ninjaIterator = NinjaGenerator();
let firstValue = ninjaIterator.next().value;
let secondValue = ninjaIterator.next().value;
console.log(firstValue, secondValue);

// console log: yoshi Hattori
```

**Somebody please help** me to understand how for-of loop work in iterator created by generator?

Comment: the return value is not a generator value. if you wnat to yield two values, put another `yield` statement behind.

Comment: The return value is a second-class citizen because it's just a "side note" to the `done: true` that the iterator returns. Returning it in `for of` would cause either annoying special cases or inconsistencies because there is no difference between a function using `return undefined`, `return` or no such statement at all so you can't differentiate between the intention to have `undefined` as last value or just ending, and in most cases you'd `yield` the things you want and then the function would return, and the return value shouldn't be looked at as part of the collection of things it yielded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `next()` has a `done` property that distinguishes the return value from the yielded values. Yielded values have `done = false`, while the returned values have `done = true`.

`for-of` processes values until `done = true`, and ignores that value. Otherwise, generators that don't have an explicit `return` statement would always produce an extra `undefined` in the `for` loop. And when you're writing the generator, you would have to code it to use `return` for the last iteration instead of `yield`, which would complicate it unnecessarily. The return value is rarely needed, since you usually just want consistent yielded values.

Comment: Would you please tell me when do we need of `return` statement in generator function ?

Comment: It's practically never needed. A generator might theoretically use it to return some kind of summary after the iteration is done. But that means you have to use explicit calls to `.next()` to get the results, rather than normal iteration syntax.